# invalid column name 'True' the error, SQLException was caugh: "Invalid column name 'True'."

Tags: c#, enums, sqlexception

This codes in DBClass.cs

```
    public DataTable Fill(string sql, params SqlParameter[] prms)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

                if (prms != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
                }

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                try
                {
                    da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
                }
                catch (Exception hata)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
                }

                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
```

> MainMenu.cs // this is main part, and below button means new student registration button

```
private void yeniÖğrenciKaydıToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Yetki.YetkiVarmi(AnaMenu.Yonetici_id, Modul.ÖğrenciKaydı, YETKI.OKU) == true)
            {
                OgrenciKaydiOlustur ogrenciKayitFormunuGoster = new OgrenciKaydiOlustur();
                ogrenciKayitFormunuGoster.ShowDialog();
                ogrenciKayitFormunuGoster.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yetkiniz Yok");
            }
        }
```

Yetki.cs //Yetki means permission

> this modul includes the application of menu names
>   public enum Modul

```
    {
        ÖğrenciKaydı = 1,
        ÖğretmenKaydı = 2,
        DanışmanKaydı = 3,
        AşamaListesi = 4,
        ÖğrenciAşamaAtaması = 5,
        ÖğrenciListesiRaporu = 6,
        ÖğretmenListesiRaporu= 7,
        ÖdemeListesiRaporu = 8,
        Yetki=9,
        AnaEkran =10
    }
```

> //this enum says, Ekle=Add, Guncelle =update , SIL = Delete, OKU=Read

public enum YETKI

```
    {
        EKLE,
        GUNCELLE,
        SIL,
        OKU
    }

public static bool YetkiVarmi(int Yonetici_id, Modul modul, YETKI yetki)
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM YETKI WHERE " + yetki.ToString() + "=True ";
                sql += " AND YONETICI_ID=" + Yonetici_id + " AND MODUL_REFNO=" + Convert.ToInt32(modul);

                bool sonuc = false;

                DBClass db = new DBClass();
                DataTable dt = db.Fill(sql);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    sonuc = true;
                }

                return sonuc;
            }
```

> and i got that error

Comment: What DB are you using? The error suggests that it doesn't recognise the word "true".

Comment: Perhaps yetki.ToString() is equal to `true`? That doesn't exist in your db

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: `True` needs to be in single quotes.

Comment: u saids for that codes ?                                           string sql = "SELECT * FROM YETKI WHERE " + yetki.ToString() + "=True ";
                sql += " AND YONETICI_ID=" + Yonetici_id + " AND MODUL_REFNO=" + Convert.ToInt32(modul);

Comment: Try `...+ yetki.ToString() + "='True' ";`.

Comment: Try displaying the value of `sql` somewhere and running it in the database by hand (in Management Studio); it will be easier to see what's happening that way.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error  TY!! it passed but i cannot give any permission for the other forms

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Answer (score 3):

`TRUE` is a reserved keyword in sql that is not used for boolean comaprisons. You should change your dynamic sql statement to this:

```
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM YETKI WHERE @yetki=1 ";
       sql += " AND YONETICI_ID=@Yonetici_id AND MODUL_REFNO=@modul";

 ...

 DataTable dt = db.Fill(sql, new SqlParameter("@yetiki", yetki.ToString()), 
              new Sqlparameter("@Yonetici_id", Yonetici_id), 
              new SqlParameter("@modul", Convert.ToInt32(modul)))
```

Assuming the column represented by `yetki.ToString()` is of type `bit`.